# Conditional derivative - #define in C

Tags: c, linux

I'm reading some `C` code and got stuck here.

Below you will find a code snippet from the header file.

```
#if NUMREPS == 0
        #define REPEAT(line) REPEAT0(line);
#elif NUMREPS == 16
        #define REPEAT(line) REPEAT16(line);
#endif
```

And the derivative for the identifier `repeat16(line);` is defined here:

```
#define REPEAT16(line) \
    line;\
    line;\
    line;\
    line;\
    line;\
    line;\
    line;\
    line;\
    line;\
    line;\
    line;\
    line;\
    line;\
    line;\
    line;\
    line;
```

What exactly does this coded snippet do? 
I took help of this [link](http://www.tru64unix.compaq.com/docs/base_doc/DOCUMENTATION/V40F_HTML/AQTLTBTE/DOCU_078.HTM) to understand the code

Comment: Which part is puzzling you?

Comment: What exactly does ` line;\ ` do?

Comment: Use `gcc -C -E sourcecode.c > sourcecode.i` to obtain the preprocessed form `sourcecode.i`. Then look inside it with a pager (`less sourcecode.i`) or an editor (`emacs sourcecode.i`).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: It is a header file (extension: .h) and not (.c)

Comment: But you usually `#include` your `header.h` in some `sourcecode.c`, and it is this `sourcecode.c` I was talking about....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The preprocessor is a step of the compilation process that is run before the actual compilation. What it does with macros is simply to replace the macro invocation with the body of the macro. So when the preprocessor see the "call" of `REPEAT16` it will simply replace that with the argument to the macro, repeated 16 times as in the body.

The argument `line` is exactly what you pass to the macro, so if you for example call it like

```
REPEAT16(printf("hello\n"))
```

then the code the compiler sees will be

```
printf("hello\n"); printf("hello\n"); printf("hello\n"); printf("hello\n"); printf("hello\n"); printf("hello\n"); printf("hello\n"); printf("hello\n"); printf("hello\n"); printf("hello\n"); printf("hello\n"); printf("hello\n"); printf("hello\n"); printf("hello\n"); printf("hello\n"); printf("hello\n");
```

The `\` character in the macro body simply tells the preprocessor that the current line continues on the next. So the whole body will be a single line.

Comment: Just a naive question: does that mean it assumes that there is `no new line character?`

Comment: It's probably worth noting that `if (false) REPEAT16(printf("hello\n"));` will print `hello` 15 times.

Comment: @user2015933 No, the preprocessor will not be adding any newline. A macro body has to be a single line, and the use of `\` is to concatenate a multi-line macro body into a single line.

Answer (score 4):

A backslash (`\`) at the end of a line is replaced by the preprocessor with the following line.

It's a common way to write multi-line macro definitions, since the replacement text must be on a single "logical" line, line-continuation is used to make it easier to read.

This is often used when using macros to define entire functions:

```
#define INT_RETURNER(x)  int return_ ## x (void)\
                         {\
                           return x;\
                         }

INT_RETURNER(4711)

int main(void)
{
  printf("%d!\n", return_4711());
}
```

Comment: why does the replacement text need to be on a single logical line?

Comment: @user2015933 Because a macro can't span more than one logical line. I'm sure the standard has some more exact language, but that's the basics.